# Integration by parts in $L^2$ subset

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Given two functions $u,v \in L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb C) \cap C^1(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$ such that $\dot u,\dot v \in L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$
I need to prove this integration by parts formula:$$\int_{\mathbb R}u\dot v \  dx=-\int_{\mathbb R}\dot u v \ dx.$$
My attempt:

by the integration per parts formula we have $$\int_{\mathbb R}u\dot v \ dx=\left[ uv \right]^{+\infty}_{-\infty}-\int_{\mathbb R}\dot u v \ dx.$$
Now $uv \in L^1$ because by Holder inequality with $p_1=p_2=\dfrac{1}{2}$ we have $\bigg|\int_{\mathbb R}uv\ dx\bigg|\le \int_{\mathbb R}|u||v|\ dx\le \|u\|_2\|v\|_2<+\infty$.

This implies that $\liminf_{x \to \pm \infty}|uv(x)|=0$.

Proof:
Assume that $\liminf_{x \to \pm \infty}|uv(x)|\neq 0$ then exist $A>0$ and $a>0$ such that $|uv(x)|>a \  \forall x >A$ and so $\int_{\mathbb R}|uv|\ dx \ge \int_{A}^{+\infty}a\ dx=+\infty$ that is $uv \not\in L^1$.

That proves that if the limit $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} uv(x)$ exists it must be $0$.

If the limit doesn't exist we can choose two sequences $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to +\infty$ such that $uv(a_n),uv(b_n) \to 0$ (because $\liminf_{x \to \pm \infty}|uv(x)|=0$).

Now the idea is that $$\int_{\mathbb R}u\dot v \ dx\underset{\text(to \ prove)}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{a_n}^{b_n}u\dot v \ dx=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(\left[ uv \right]^{b_n}_{a_n}-\int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dot u v \ dx\right)=-\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dot u v \ dx\underset{\text(to \ prove)}=-\int_{\mathbb R}\dot u v \ dx.$$

I need to prove that for example $\int_{\mathbb R}u\dot v \ dx=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_{a_n}^{b_n}u\dot v \ dx$ the idea is using that $\int_{a_n}^{b_n}u\dot v \ dx= \int_{\mathbb R} u \dot v \chi_{[a_n,b_n]} \ dx$ and using Dominated Convergence Theorem because 1) $u \dot v \chi_{[a_n,b_n]} \to u \dot v$ and 2) exists a positive function $g \in L^1$ such that $|u \dot v \chi_{[a_n,b_n]}(x)|\le g(x) \ \ \forall x$ and we can choose $g=|u \dot v|$.

Let me know if I did something wrong.

Comment: If $u,u'\in L_2$ then $u\cdot u'\in L_1$. So if $f=u^2$, then $f\in L_1$ and $f'\in L_1$. From the fundamental theorem of calculus $f(b)-f(a)=\int^b_af'$ as $f'\in L_1$, $\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}f(a)$ exists. Similarly  $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}f(b)$ exists. From that, and the integrability of $f$ you can prove that the limits are in fact $0$, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)=0$; hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}u(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u,u'\in L_2$ then $u\cdot u'\in L_1$. So if $f=u^2$, then $f\in L_1$ and $f'\in L_1$. If in addition $u'$ is continuous, then, from the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$f(b)-f(a)=\int^b_af'$$
Since $f'\in L_1$, $\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}f(a)$ exists. Similarly  $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}f(b)$ exists. From that, and the integrability of $f$ you can prove that the limits are in fact $0$, i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)=0$; hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}u(x)=0$.
For example, since $f\in L_1$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_x|f|=0$$
If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=B\neq0$, then for all $x$ large enough we would have $|f(x)|>\frac{|B|}{2}$ and so $\int^\infty_x|f|\geq \int^\infty_x|B|/2\,ds=\infty$ for all $x$ large enough, contradicting the integrability of $f$.

Hence, in your problem, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}u(x)v(x)=0$